# Clean rows with certain values in R

Tags: r

I want to exclude every row from database where gender!="M" and gender!="F" and clean the database.

Thanks, in advance.

This is what I have tried:

```
CleanGender<-which(data$Gender!="M" & data$Gender!="F")
```

Comment: Please add a sample of your data with `dput(head(data,12))` or simply copy and paste the output of `head(data)` to the question.

Comment: I think the `&` is the issue.  You can't have both elements in the same row  You may need `subset(data, gender %in% c("M", "F"))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%in%` to subset multiple values on a column.  It would check whether these values are present in the column, create a logical expression and subset those rows

```
subset(data, gender %in% c("M", "F"))
```

Comment: I see, you're right!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing gender can't be both 'M' and 'F' (`which` look sequentially at vector rows) :

```r
# find index you want to keep
CleanGender_index <- which(data$Gender!="M" | data$Gender!="F")

# select corresponding rows, renaming your data frame is called `df_raw`
df_clean <- df_raw[CleanGender_index, ]
```

`data` may not the best name for your dataset since it is also an R function.